# How to localize Symfony2 forms?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a Symfony2 form where a user can enter an address which is now in a fixed format and since we want to offer our software internationally I am looking for the best way to implement this in SF.

Instead of making one generic `address type` we'd like to localize the forms with one generic format as fallback for unsupported locales.

I want to separate layout and localization (order, grouping, labels, translations, mandatory and optional fields) from the processing (PHP/SF) of the forms and the actual rendering (TWIG).

What I came up was this: create a `address` form type from a database model which contains all possible fields. Render this form type in twig automatically by calling `form_widget(form)` or by rendering individual fields when needed. And lastly; define the "layout" of a form in some kind of config format (YML, array, whatever) and extend the default TWIG form rendering to itterate through the form elements defined in said config.

For example the address config for The Netherlands and the US would be:

```
- NL-nl
  - [firstname, infix, lastname]
  - [street1, number]
  - [postcode, city]
- EN-us
  - [fullname]
  - [street1]
  - [street2]
  - [city, state]
  - [zip]
```

Later we'll add localized labels, classes, optional and mandatory fields, etc to this configuration.

For now our big question is: where to put this config? Use a simple array in the `finishView` class? Put the config in a YML file that's parsed by the form types that need a localized form layout?

Any information from people that encountered this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> Later we'll add localized labels, classes, optional and mandatory fields, etc to this configuration.

[The localized labels is automatic process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) where they can be translated and converted based on the user's locale. The mandatory fields could be resolved using constraints.

> where to put this config?

In my opinion this should be made directly into the entity and form type:

You can create an `LocaleAddressType` and to add these fields depending on current "locale" value, but first, you needs to have an Entity with all possible fields related to "address" approach.

#### The `LocaleAddress` entity:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/LocaleAddress.php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class LocaleAddress
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"nl-NL", ...})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstName;

    // ...
}
```

Includes all distinct fields for all possible locales and settings these with `nullable=true`. Plus, use the `NotBlank` constraint and `groups` option to validate required fields per locale.

#### The config file

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/locale_address_form.yml
address_form:
   nl-NL:
      - [firstname, infix, lastname]
      - [street1, number]
      - [postcode, city]
   en-US:
      - [fullname]
      - [street1]
      - [street2]
      - [city, state]
      - [zip]
```

#### The compound `LocaleAddressType` adds some fields depending on the `locale` option, by default it is [`Locale::getDefault()`](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php)

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/LocaleAddressType.php

class LocaleAddressType extends AbstractType
{ 
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $config = $this->loadLocaleFormConfig($options['locale']);

        foreach ($config as $fields) {
            foreach (fields as $field) {
                $builder->add($field);
            }
        }
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['config'] = $this->loadLocaleFormConfig($options['locale']);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\LocaleAddress',
            'locale', \Locale::getDefault(),
        ]);

        // force that validation groups will equal to configured locale.
        $resolver->setNormalizer('validation_groups', function (Options $options) {
            return [$options['locale']];
        });

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('locale', ['string']);

        // pending validate the custom locale value.
    }

    private function loadLocaleFormConfig($locale) 
    {
        $config = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('path/to/locale_address_form.yml'));

        return $config['address_form'][$locale];        
    }
}
```

**Note:** On submit that fields are validated in correspondence with the `locale` value.

Register the form type:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.locale_address:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\LocaleAddressType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

#### Using the Form

Now, you can use this form type in other forms with `localeAddress` field associacion.

```
$build->add('localeAddress', LocaleAddressType::class);
```

When the locale in your application is changed `\Locale::setDefault` this will affects the form fields to display.

#### Creating a Template for the Field

> I want to separate layout and localization (order, grouping, labels, translations, mandatory and optional fields) from the processing (PHP/SF) of the forms and the actual rendering (TWIG).

```
{% block locale_address_widget %}
    {% for fields in config %}
        <div class="row">
        {% set n = 12 // fields|length %}
        {% for field in fields %}
            <div class="col-md-{{ n }}">
                {{ form_row(form[field]) }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The code is Symfony3-based.

Comment: If you need this for Symfony2 < 2.8 please tells me and will changes the answer.

Comment: We actually use 2.7, but I don't think your solution is the one we're looking for. What if we create a localized form for each of the 200-something countries in the world? That switch will be huge and filled with redundant code. Sure we can move the redundant parts to a helper or something, but still; where are we going to define the layout of the form elements?

We are still convinced that defining all possible values in one single form type and rendering them according to the locales described in the config is the cleanest way to go. The big question is: where and how to this config?

Comment: Well, you can create a config yml file like you has described and load it in form type, next, be sure to load only the config of the current locale, next, add those corresponding fields to the form builder. In the other hand, in your twig layout, pass the same locale config and use `.col-md-N` classes to create the inline inputs and `.row` to new lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

- You can create different form types for each country
- You can create one form type with all fields and then with form events remove fields which aren't relevated to currently selected country
- You can create different views per country and one big form type

Comment: The second option is what we want to build. But a little different, because we also need to define the layout (order, etc), grouping (first- and lastname inline), constraints (zipcodes!) and other custom stuff like classes to trigger specific JS bindings, etc.